# Convex cone necessary and sufficient condition

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-cone

Let C be a nonempty set in $R^n$ . Show that C is a convex cone if and only
if $x_1, x_2 \in C $ implies that $\lambda_1\cdot x_1 + \lambda_2\cdot x_2 \in C $ for all $\lambda_1 ,\lambda_2 \geq0$.

Comment: That is an order. What is the question?

Comment: I want to know how can I prove  "C is a convex cone  iff  x1,x2∈C implies that λ1⋅x1+λ2⋅x2∈C, for all λ1,λ2≥0". Since I think it is exactly the definition of convex cone. I'm confused about how can I start with.

Comment: You need to show some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $C$ is a convex cone use that $\lambda_i = \frac{\lambda_i} {\lambda_1 + \lambda_2} \cdot (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)$, for $i=1,2$.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I didn't get it.

Comment: The $\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}$ sum up to $1$ and $(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)x_i \in C$ by assumption.